# Showing that two test statistics are equivalent

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Suppose we want to know if there is a significant difference in the mean weight change for different types of treatments. We have three treatments $A$, $B$, $C$ and denote the mean weight change by $\overline{A}$, $\overline{B}$ and $\overline{C}$ respectively. Define $M=\frac{1}{3}(\overline{A}+\overline{B}+\overline{C})$. We have 21 patients that we divide in 3 groups of 7. Now I have to show that the two test statistics $T=(\overline{A}-M)^2+(\overline{B}-M)^2+(\overline{C}-M)^2$ and $S=\overline{A}^2+\overline{B}^2+\overline{C}^2$ are equivalent in the sense that they result in the same testing procedure.

I don't know what is meant by this question. I can't find a definition of equivalency between two test statistics. I thought maybe that I should show that the p-value of both tests is the same, but there are $\frac{21!}{7!7!7!}$ possibilities. So how should I interpret this question?

Comment: $\sum (X_i - \bar X)^2 = \sum X_i^2 + n\bar X^2.$ For normal dta sample var $S^2$ stochastically indep of $\bar X.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

The expansion of $T$ will involve $\overline{A}^2$,  $\overline{B}^2$ and $\overline{C}^2$ terms so try to express $T$ as $S+f(M)$ for some function of $M$

Consider what might be counted as extreme values of $T$. Very high ones? Very low ones? Similarly for $S$

Given $M$, is there a direct correspondence between extreme values of $T$ and extreme values of $S$?  What does that suggest about testing the two statistics?

Comment: Thank you! By working out these steps, I came to the conclusion that both the statistics require $\overline{A}$, $\overline{B}$ and $\overline{C}$ to be very close to each other to get to the extreme values. Is this the same as saying that they are equivalent, in the sense that they have the same testing procedure?

Comment: @Rinus94 Having $\overline{A}$,  $\overline{B}$ and $\overline{C}$ very close to each other will make $T$ very small, and clearly $T$ cannot be negative.  For given $M$ it will also minimise $S$. But does this really count as extreme in the sense of distinguishing between your null and alternative hypotheses?

Comment: We can distinguish between the null and alternative hypotheses if $T$ is large. And I find it hard to say what extreme values for $S$ are. $T$ will be large if $S$ is large. So extreme values are large ones for $S$, and large ones for $T$?